# convert toolframe coordinate to world frame coordinates?

Tags: kinematics, matlab, visualization

I am not sure how i should explain this, I am looking for a way to plot the trajectory an robot arm.  An object is seen from the toolFrame frame, but how do I plot the position of each joint, such that the frame they uses are the same.

One way would be to use the world frame as reference, but how would i plot the position of the object related to the world frame?

Comment: What environment are you drawing in? Matlab? Is there a mathematical model of the robot available in that environment?

Comment: Matlab.. 
I have a mathmatical model, but not coded in matlab. At  the moment  I just multply different transformation matrices to get the point i want the desired transformation

Comment: "*An object is seen from the toolFrame frame*" this is what makes it a little unclear to me what you want exactly. Do you want to visualize the trajectories in the tool frame?

Comment: The position of the object is given relative to the tool frame.

Comment: I would like to visualize trajectory of the whole robot arm, each joint..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have solved the inverse kinematics (IK) problem already...

I suppose you have a transformation matrix for each joint, build up from one line in the DH table (if you used DH to describe the robot).
Form the IK you have obtained

$Q = [q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4, q_5, q_6]$

Having all Q values you can now write:

$H_{0,1} = A_1(q_1)$

$\Rightarrow$ $H_{0,1}(1:3, 4)$ will give you the $x$, $y$ and $z$ Coordinates of joint 1

$H_{0,2} = H_{0,1}*A_2(q_2)$

$\Rightarrow$ $H_{0,2}(1:3, 4)$ will give you the $x$, $y$ and $z$ Coordinates of joint 2

$H_{0,3} = H_{0,2}*A_3(q_3)$

$\Rightarrow$ $H_{0,3}(1:3, 4)$ will give you the $x$, $y$ and $z$ Coordinates of joint 3

$H_{0,4} = H_{0,3}*A_4(q_4)$

$\Rightarrow$ $H_{0,4}(1:3, 4)$ will give you the $x$, $y$ and $z$ Coordinates of joint 4

$H_{0,5} = H_{0,4}*A_5(q_5)$

$\Rightarrow$ $H_{0,5}(1:3, 4)$ will give you the $x$, $y$ and $z$ Coordinates of joint 5

$H_{0,6} = H_{0,5}*A_6(q_6)$

$\Rightarrow$ $H_{0,6}(1:3, 4)$ will give you the $x$, $y$ and $z$ Coordinates of joint 6

$H_{0,tool} = H_{0,6}*A_{tool}$

**where**

- $A_i$ is the DH-transformation matrix associated with joint $i$.
- the index $_0$ represents the world frame
- the intex $_{tool}$ represents the tool frame
- $H_{i,j}$ represent the transformation matrix from frame $i$ to frame $j$

Comment: What about the position of the object related to the world?

Comment: I don't know if thats wasn't clear, but my problem is the axis is misalligned,  as the position of objected is logged according to the tool

Comment: If you solved the inverse kinematics then it does not matter...that is why the answer starts with "asuming you have solved the IK"

Comment: did you solve the IK?

Comment: I've solved the invkin for the robot

Comment: Then you have all the q values, just use them as above and the final H matrix should correspond to the pose of the tool, expressed in world frame.

Comment: but how about the ball?...

Comment: I am not sure i understand how you want me to plot it?? it seems to me that you are mixing multiple frames?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have all the joint angles ($Q$). Those define the pose of the robot regardless of any other frames. Those are always expressed in their local frames. The transition from world frame to frame of joint 1 is $A_1$. The transition is dependent on joint angle and robot geometry only. You transition by multiplication and plot the frame origin (x, y and z). Then you go to the next joint and plot the frame origin and so on until you reach the end-effector. At the end you will get the location of each joint in world frame. connect the lines and you can draw your robot.